# What does "State" mean in Android fragment

Tags: android

In android, we keeps talking about retain the activity state/fragment state, but I have this question, what does "state" mean indeed. For example, suppose I have the following DialogFragment

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
  private String mMessage;

  @Override
  public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     ((TextView) v.findViewById("message")).setText(mMessage);
  }
}
```

But wouldn't "mMessage" be retained as a member variable during device rotation? So in this case, does "mMessage" considered a state that I have to retain and put into argument when creating this fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a device rotation, the currently visible Activity is destroyed.  Some widgets such as DialogFragment save and restore their own state.

[Handling Configuration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: From the example provided by the official doc, it seems the fragment state can be retained by retaining the instance of the fragment itself with the following line `setRetainInstance(true)`. Is it still necessary to put the parameters into arguments?

Comment: Correct.  From the configuration doc "When the Android system shuts down your activity due to a configuration change, the fragments of your activity that you have marked to retain are not destroyed. You can add such fragments to your activity to preserve stateful objects. 1. Extend the Fragment class and declare references to your stateful objects.
2. Call setRetainInstance(boolean) when the fragment is created.
3. Add the fragment to your activity.
4. Use FragmentManager to retrieve the fragment when the activity is restarted."

Answer (score 0):

The concept of State comes from OOP, not from android, to simplify: an object has a state (the data) and a behavior (the code).

Fragments and Activities work a bit different, fragments will retain the state if they are stopped, but they will lose it of the activity that manages them is destroyed (unless you retain it). Activities, however, will lose the state upon change of configuration.

The doc explains the lifecycle and how/when to retain fragments:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: You are right about member variable in activity, but fragment I don't think you are correct. See https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Comment: You are correct, I was too general, I updated the answer.